# WordPress: get post_parent title

Tags: wordpress, parent, title

I've created a custom sidebar that grabs the post parent's pages:

```
query_posts("post_type=page&post_parent=6");
```

I'd like to grab the title of the post_parent (i.e. "About"). `the_title` won't work because it's the title of the child pages.

How can I output the post_parent title?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you've already got the ID of the parent post, so you can just use this:

```
<?php
    $parent_post_id = 6;
    $parent_post = get_post($parent_post_id);
    $parent_post_title = $parent_post->post_title;
    echo $parent_post_title;
?>
```

(Insert your parent post id at $parent_post_id)

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite follow. Let's say my parent post id is 6. Should the code be *<?php $parent_post_title = 6->post_title; ?>*? If so, does it need to be in the loop, or will a simple preceding echo work?

Comment: Sorry, didn't let me edit comment above.
See edited version of code above.  It doesn't need to be in the loop, you can just do:

`<?php
$parent_post_id = 6;
$parent_post = get_post($parent_post_id);
$parent_post_title = $parent_post->post_title;
echo $parent_post_title;
?>`

Comment: Just found this code which doesn't require hard-coding the page id: *$parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent); echo $parent_title;*

Comment: @Ryan Niiiiiice! This is what people are looking for that come to this page via search. No hardcoding, no time-wasting, just c/p and works. :-)

Comment: Could you post this code as an answer below and change the mark from this answer to the new one?

Answer (score 38):

```
echo get_the_title( $post->post_parent );
```

or

```
echo get_the_title( X );
```

Where X is any valid post/page ID.

No need to get a complete post object just for one property.

Comment: Thanks! This is nice and clean and just what I needed

Answer (score 5):

This is the clean and nice code you need:

It is also save to use when there is more than one parent hierarchy level.

```
<?php 

    $current = $post->ID;

    $parent = $post->post_parent;

    $grandparent_get = get_post($parent);

    $grandparent = $grandparent_get->post_parent;

    ?>

    <?php if ($root_parent = get_the_title($grandparent) !== $root_parent = get_the_title($current)) {echo get_the_title($grandparent); }else {echo get_the_title($parent); }?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it's super old question, but in case anyone was looking for some nice one-liner. Here it is:

```
echo get_the_title( wp_get_post_parent_id( get_the_ID() ) );
```

If you want to keep title filter go with:

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_title', get_the_title( wp_get_post_parent_id( get_the_ID() ) ) );
```

Answer (score 3):

WordPress 5.7 introduces a new helper function to more easily fetch the parent post's ID:
`get_parent_post()`

This can also be used in conjunction with `has_parent_post()`, so you could have something like looks like:

```
<?php if ( has_parent_post() ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink( get_parent_post() ); ?>">
        <?php the_title( get_parent_post() ); ?>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Note that these functions accept a "child post ID" as a parameter, which defaults to the current post.

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/02/10/introducing-new-post-parent-related-functions-in-wordpress-5-7/

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this, it will grab the parent post and then echo the parents title and such. Have a look and let me know if it works for you.

https://gist.github.com/1140481

This should even work outside of the wordpress loop as well.